Ceiling wiring for pendant lamp
Trying to connect a pendant light with one blue, one red, and one green/yellow wire.
Picture of my ceiling: Copper wire, Black single wire, two white wires (they were connected, and I found later one was hot, so I marked it with black tape. I left them separate to show the difference in the picture). I did not use the other wires, two black and one white that are connected. I believe the 2 black are hot and the white is neutral but I am not sure.
The first time I connected, green/yellow to house ground, black to red, and blue to 2 whites, the light turned on, but when I turned it off to mount the housing it would not come on again. I have taken it down a couple of times and tried to rewire but it is still not working. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!




Your ceiling colors sound like US/Canada. Your light colors sound like something else. Is the light listed for US/Canada us - UL, ETL or similar?

Your “hot” white wire is probably a neutral coming from an another light. It’s reading as hot because the voltage is flowing through the other light. You’ll probably now find a light that no longer works.

Ok that makes sense, thank you! What about the two black and one white?

This is US wiring. The light was manufactured in China and came with minimal directions. Ill try to upload a pix of the directions.

The light is (nominally) designed for worldwide use. The problem is that if, as I suspect is the case, it has not been properly tested/listed for use in the US with a NRTL (UL, ETL, etc.) then if there should ever be a problem - e.g., a fire caused by a fault in this light fixture - your insurance will not pay. Basically all hard-wired equipment needs to either be UL or ETL (or comparable, but those are the main ones) listed or be specifically approved (i.e., gone through a permit process with the local inspector).

Would it be possible to replace the led if that is the problem?

@tlane NRTL listing is not about any specific component. It is about the entire device. Every piece - wire size, insulation type/thickness, connection quality (screws, soldering, etc.), LED driver quality (some are total junk that have (a) a high risk of mains 120V getting through, posing a safety hazard and/or (b) are incredibly inefficient, resulting in wasting energy), proper grounding (so you can't touch the fixture and get shocked), etc. The LED itself is probably the least of the concerns - LEDs that aren't any good generally don't produce good quality light and are relatively obvious.

Ok thank you that make sense.
